# Need assistance in handling Alerts - waiting for alert to be present & Unhandled Alert exception

Tags: java, selenium

I have the below Alert. The problem is that is returning error on `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())` line from `UnhandledAlertException`, even though i can see the alert triggered on-screen. If i remove the `UnhandledAlertException`, then i get error that i have an `UnhandledAlertException`. Can you please provide a solution to this, and some explanation so i understand what happened? 
`

```
//Alert
    Alert getAlert() {
        try{
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertCheck = alert.getText();
        this.bcase = true;
        System.out.println(alertCheck);
        if(alertCheck.equals("Define higher than 0 quantity for all products")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");
        } else if(alertCheck.equals("Invalid Payment Document Number")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");
        }else if (alertCheck.equals("Define rates for all products")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");
        } else if (alertCheck.equals("Define delivery dates for all products")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");
        } else if(alertCheck.equals("NOT IMPLEMENTED YET - WAITING DELIVERY DOC INPUT")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");
        }else if (alertCheck.equals("You must upload an invoice file!")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");
        } else if (alertCheck.equals("You must upload a payment order file!")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");
        } else if (alertCheck.equals("Invalid Payment Document Date")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");
        } else if (alertCheck.equals("Invalid Payment Document Number")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");}  
        else if (alertCheck.equals("Invalid Payment Document Date")){
            m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");} 
        else if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn pull-left btn-default input-sm'][text()='Open Order Request']")).isDisplayed()){
            this.bcase = false;
            m.print("(FAIL!!!) The user can advance with unselected/wrongly completed fields, even though an error message is present! (FAIL!!!)");
        }   else {m.print("(FAIL!!!) The user cannot advance, but there is no pop-up message informing him of the problem! (FAIL!!!)");}
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        return alert;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e){
            m.print("(FAIL!!!) The user can advance with wrongly completed fields, without any error popup to inform them! (FAIL!!!)");
            this.bcase = false; 
            return null;
        } catch (UnhandledAlertException f){
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            String alertCheck = alert.getText();
            if (alertCheck.equals("You must upload an invoice file! You must upload a payment order file!")){
                m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");
            } else if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn pull-left btn-default input-sm'][text()='Open Order Request']")).isDisplayed()){
                this.bcase = false;
                m.print("(FAIL!!!) The user can advance with unselected/wrongly completed fields, even though an error message is present! (FAIL!!!)");
            }driver.switchTo().alert().accept();return null;
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Consider using a `switch` instead of the big `if/else if` block. This will make the code much more readable and maintainable.
Also, this is a lot of boilerplate code `m.print("Correct error message appeared! User cannot advance further!");` Try creating a `String message` object prior to your statement and do `m.print(message);`.

Comment: And what happens with this test `else if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn pull-left btn-default input-sm'][text()='Open Order Request']")).isDisplayed()){
            this.bcase = false;
            m.print("(FAIL!!!) The user can advance with unselected/wrongly completed fields, even though an error message is present! (FAIL!!!)");`? Since i switch after alertCheck and that is not an alertCheck statement. And also, how i integrate the Exceptions into the `case` scenarios?

Comment: You may put the non-alertCheck part under default section of the `switch` statement. The Exceptions are fine, they should work exactly the same with a `switch` as they do now.

Comment: Ok, and how should i do the exceptions then? because if i say `switch(alertCheck)`, how can i then write `case Exception`? Exception won't be a string, so i think it won;t work.

Comment: You do not handle exceptions within your switch statement. You do `try {switch} catch (exception e) {handle e};`.

Comment: Ahaaa...that was what i was looking for, thanks!. Now it's clear, the code is almost ready i'll edit it in my question if i still encounter the problem after re-writing it. And where should i place the `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()`? Before the catch or at the end?

Comment: It's good where it is now. However, since you have already switched to the alert (line 4 of your code), you only need to `alert.accept()`. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better approach to handle alerts is first wait the alert to appear, and than handle it. You can do this, with this two methods:

```
public boolean checkNativeAlert() {
    boolean exist = false;

    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 3);
        if(!(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()) == null)) {
            exist = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ignore) {}

    return exist;
}

public String getNativeTextAlert(boolean close) {
    String text = null;
    try {
        Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
        text = alert.getText();
        if (close) {
            alert.accept();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ignore) {}

    return text;
}
```

Handle alerts with Selenium is a bit tricky, from my point of view is better use this two other options:

- Change alerts to modal dialogs (at least in the debug/test mode)
- Use autoIt to handle alerts in Selenium tests

Comment: In the example above, i think close has a null value as i can't see it initialized anywhere, only declared.

Comment: close Is the function's parameter